# Multiple regex matches in single expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following sensitive data:

```
"Password":"123","RootPassword":"123qwe","PassPhrase":"phrase"
```

I would like to get the following safe data:

```
"Password":"***","RootPassword":"***","PassPhrase":"***"
```

It's my code:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = "\"Password\":\"123\",\"RootPassword\":\"123qwe\",\"PassPhrase\":\"phrase\"";

        var safe1 = PasswordReplacer.Replace1(data);
        var safe2 = PasswordReplacer.Replace2(data);
    }
}

public static class PasswordReplacer
{
    private const string RegExpReplacement = "$1***$2";
    private const string Template = "(\"{0}\":\").*?(\")";

    private static readonly string[] PasswordLiterals =
    {
        "password",
        "RootPassword",
        "PassPhrase"
    };

    public static string Replace1(string sensitiveInfo)
    {
        foreach (var literal in PasswordLiterals)
        {
            var pattern = string.Format(Template, literal);
            var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            sensitiveInfo = regex.Replace(sensitiveInfo, RegExpReplacement);
        }

        return sensitiveInfo;
    }
    
    public static string Replace2(string sensitiveInfo)
    {
       var multiplePattern = "(\"password\":\")|(\"RootPassword\":\")|(\"PassPhrase\":\").*?(\")"; //?
        var regex = new Regex(string.Format(Template, multiplePattern), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return regex.Replace(sensitiveInfo, RegExpReplacement);
    }
}
```

`Replace1` method works as expected. But it does it one by one. My question is is it possble to do the same but using single regex match ? If so I need help with `Replace2`.

Comment: You can try thinks out on sites like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/). In this case you at least need to combine the three groups into a single group. `((\"Password\":\")|(\"RootPassword\":\")|(\"PassPhrase\":\")).*?(\")`. But you cannot process the regex through the `Template`, as that will result in something weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Replace2` can look like

```cs
public static string Replace2(string sensitiveInfo)
{
    var multiplePattern = $"(\"(?:{string.Join("|", PasswordLiterals)})\":\")[^\"]*(\")"; 
    return Regex.Replace(sensitiveInfo, multiplePattern, RegExpReplacement, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/0FPIst).

The `multiplePattern` will hold a pattern like `("(?:password|RootPassword|PassPhrase)":")[^"]*(")`, see the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%22%28%3f%3apassword%7cRootPassword%7cPassPhrase%29%22%3a%22%29%5b%5e%22%5d*%28%22%29&i=%22Password%22%3a%22123%22%2c%22RootPassword%22%3a%22123qwe%22%2c%22PassPhrase%22%3a%22phrase%22&r=%241***%242&o=i). Quick details:

- `("(?:password|RootPassword|PassPhrase)":")` - Group 1 (`$1`): a `"` char followed with either `password`, `RootPassword` or `PassPhrase` and then a `":"` substring
- `[^"]*` - any zero or more chars other than `"` as many as possible
- `(")` - Group 2 (`$2`): a `"` char.